# en el campo de texto del correo me aparece [email protected]. ¿Como quitarlo?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, web

Resulta que tengo un datatable que me lista datos personales de personas, y uno de ellos es el correo, cuando lo pruebo de manera local, se ve bien el correo, pero desde el sitio de producción me muestra el correo con la palabra [email protected]. 
el resultado del correo que muestro, viene desde la base datos, y utilizo C# con razor para visualizarlo.

estuve viendo una posible solución para quitar [email protected] y mostrar el correo. En la solución era colocar al @ el tag , es decir así: `@`, pero lo estuve intentando utilizando un replace de la siguiente forma:

```
 .....
<td>
  @item.email.Replace("@","<code>@</code>")
</td> 
...... //resto de codigo
```

pero al intentarlo de esta forma, no me reconoce el tag code, sino que lo considera como string, mostrandose por ejemplo asi:
 correoprueba`@`gmail.com

La otra solución que yo creo, es hacer alguna habilitacion de javascripts en el servidor, de donde está el sitio alojado, pero no se que debería hacer.

¿Alguna idea de como solucionar este problema? Espero sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he encontrado una solución. Lo tuve que hacer así:

```
 Html.Raw(item.email.Replace("@","<code>@</code>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo el correo entre estas etiquetas

```html
<!-Email_off-> junior@gmail.com <!-/Email_off->
```

Comment: Lamentablemente no funciona, pero pille una solución.

Comment: genial lo importante es que lo solucionaste. saludos